# Accessing functions of data.table fields via strings; or, how to imitate data= in lm

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to build a matrix of variables derived from `data.table` fields;

For concreteness let's say I have a data.table `dt` with variables `x1`,`x2`,`x3`, and I want to make the `nrow(dt)`x4 matrix with columns `x1`,`log(x1)`,`as.numeric(as.factor(x3))`, and `3*x2-x1`.

A one-off solution is to call

```
cbind(dt$x1, log(dt$x1), as.numeric(as.factor(data$x3)), 3 * data$x2-data$x1)
```

But I'd like something more malleable--I'm doing a bunch of other stuff with this matrix later.

I'd like to do so in the same vain as `lm` when specifying a `data=` argument, where I have the luxury of pulling variables from a string list to execute a regression--for example, if I have `var_names` (including functions of the variables, such as `"log(x1)"` or `"as.factor(x2)"`), I can call `lm(y ~ as.formula(paste(var_names[5:8], collapse = "+")), data = dt)` and it will execute properly.

Because of the functions applied to the variables, my first instinct--to use `[[`--doesn't work:

```
dt[["log(x1)"]] = NULL
```

More promising was to evaluate things in `j`, but I couldn't get this to work either:

```
dt[ , log(x1)] # is fine, but I don't know how to access this from "log(x1)"
dt[ , "log(x1)"] = "log(x1)" #whomp
dt[ , get("log(x1)")] #Error--looking for object named log(x1), as with [[
dt[ , as.formula("log(x1)")] #getting warmer--looks for x1 in the global environment
```

I'm not sure how to specify the environment for `dt`; I tried to understand how calling `data=` for `lm` works, but wasn't making any headway.

But if the environment for `dt` is `envdt`, I think this would work:

```
dt[ , as.formula("log(x1)", env = envdt)]
```

If I can get this to work, I'll loop through the character vector to get my matrix:

```
mat <- c()
for (vv in var_names){
   mat <- cbind(mat, dt[ , as.formula(vv, env = envdt)])
}
```

Anyone have a suggestion for how to call the correct environment (i.e., imitate `lm`), or another approach to get the matrix I'm looking for in a programmatic way?

Comment: A data table is a bit like using `with`, for example look at `dt[, environment()]`. Note that it does not return the global env. But as it stands your problem is not reproducible.  Please provide some data so we can do what you are doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option that uses `.SD` as the environment to evaluate your expressions in.  `.SD` represents the current `data.table` (or at least the current sub-group less the grouping variables, but since we're not grouping it's the same as the whole table):

```
dt <- data.table(x1=1:10, x2=1:10, x3=1:10)
calls <- expression(x1, log(x1), as.numeric(as.factor(x3)), 3 * x2 - x1)
mx <- as.matrix(dt[, lapply(calls, eval, envir=.SD)])   # <- note `.SD`

colnames(mx) <- sapply(calls, deparse, width=500)       # Make pretty 
mx
```

Produces:

```
      x1   log(x1) as.numeric(as.factor(x3)) 3 * x2 - x1
 [1,]  1 0.0000000                         1           2
 [2,]  2 0.6931472                         2           4
 [3,]  3 1.0986123                         3           6
 [4,]  4 1.3862944                         4           8
 [5,]  5 1.6094379                         5          10
 [6,]  6 1.7917595                         6          12
 [7,]  7 1.9459101                         7          14
 [8,]  8 2.0794415                         8          16
 [9,]  9 2.1972246                         9          18
[10,] 10 2.3025851                        10          20
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate on why this works, but `dt[,as.formula("log(x1)",env=.SD)]` does not? Also, is there a clear tie between how this is working and how `lm` actualizes the `data=` argument?

Comment: @MichaelChirico, I'm not very familiar with `as.formula`, but it seems like it just won't do what you think it should be doing (i.e. produce an expression to evaluate).  `as.formula` creates formulas provided the string you provide includes a `~`.  Formulas are close to quoted calls, which is what you want.  Both `quote` and `expression` produce quoted calls.  In addition to that, you need to evaluate the calls as well.  `data.table` doesn't do it automatically for you.  In the example above, we use `lapply` to apply `eval` to each member of the `calls` expression.

Comment: For future reference, I also found it useful in what I was doing to know that I could have gone from a character vector to an expression object via `parse(text=char_vec)` which converts `char_vec` to an expression--to which we can then use Brodie's approach, e.g. `sapply(parse(text=char_vec),eval)`.